# Viewing escaped characters in database mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am using mysqli prepared statement to insert values into the database. I know that this extension handles characters escaping properly.

I have a file path : `images/serveover/Bellini 83.png`, what I am expecting to see after insert is the file path with escaped characters in the database, something like `images\/serveover\/Bellini 83.png` but I only see the image path as is.

How can I make sure that my string has been properly escaped? Is this view standard in phpMyAdmin where It does not show escaped characters or is it just hiding them on view?

Below is my insert prepared statement with params where all the values are being filled properly :

```
 $insertQuery  = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO images (image_id, image_date_created, image_date_modified, image_title, image_src, category_id, image_status, image_external_file, another_id) VALUES (null, NOW(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?, ?, ?,'A', ?, ?)");

 if($insertQuery ) 
 {              
    $insertQuery -> bind_param("ssisi", $title, $image, $row["category_id"], $file, $row["id"]);            
    $insertQuery -> execute();              
    $insertQuery -> close();
  }
```

Comment: You escape the characters so that it __can be__ inserted in the database cleanly, so it doesn't store it in the database with the escapes but as simple data.... if the data hadn't been properly escaped, then it would have failed to insert into the database

Comment: So it does not necessarily escape characters by adding `\\` to the string right?

Comment: Note that if you're using bind variables in a prepared statement, then this effectively "escapes" strings for you, you don't do it yourself.... but if you're not using bind vars, then SQL wouldn't know whether a `'` was part of a string, or marked the end of a string unless you escaped it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're dealing with strings, the escaping process simply instructs MySQL to ignore the special properties of a character and treat it like a normal character.

> Bob\'s special string

Is entered into the database as

> Bob's special string

It's important to note that prepared statements don't use escaping at all. Prepared statements send the query in one set and the data in another, so MySQL doesn't need to escape it, since it knows that's the actual value to store.

You can read more about the process in the MySQL manual
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html

Comment: so if I have `$city = " 's Hertogenbosch ";` and i use `$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $city);` I will see `'s Hertogenbosch` in the database right? If yes, what is the escaping process really doing here?  Is it just notifying the DB engine that there is a special character and not affecting the way the string is inserted to DB?

Comment: No, escaping works exactly the way you think it should, adding a backslash in front of the troublesome `'` The DB engine then treats `'` as a normal character and saves it just like that.

Comment: I think I got this understood. Thanks for your help :)